# Desenhar fora da área de um form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Usando C# com o tipo de projeto Windows Forms Application é possível desenhar coisas fora do form? Eu gostaria de desenhar um quadrado esticável pelo mouse e reposicionável, por onde devo começar?

Segue uma imagem como exemplo do que eu procuro:
[image]

O objetivo na verdade é meio que tirar uma *print* de tal área, se tivesse outro modo seria muito bom também :)

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que procurava saber? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora? Se não, precisa que algo mais seja melhorado?

Answer (score 1):

Segunda essa [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14398452/221800) é possível de duas formas, ambas com deficiências:

```
var f = new Form();
f.BackColor = Color.White;
f.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
f.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
f.TopMost = true;
f.TransparencyKey = Color.White;
```

É fácil o usuário sair de sua aplicação e nem perceber com <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>, fora dela não vai funcionar. Ou seja é uma bela gambiarra.

Ou pode não usar um `Form`. Um código simplificadamente seria assim (ele pode ser melhor escrito):

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hwnd);
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern void ReleaseDC(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr dc);

...


IntPtr desktopPtr = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromHdc(desktopPtr);
var b = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
g.FillRectangle(b, new Rectangle(0, 0, 1920, 1080)); //o algoritmo seria mais sofisticado
g.Dispose();
ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, desktopPtr);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/Draw.cs).

Se a tela for atualizada, o desenho irá sumir, dá para ir redesenhando ele.

Na prática a solução passa por algo bem mais sofisticado.

Se eu achar algum outro método, eu atualizo aqui.

Comment: Eu estava pensando em um form com a background transparente, ai o usuário arrastaria pela parte superior da janela e redimensionaria normalmente como se faz com uma janela, oque você acha?

Comment: Isso é o que eu respondi, mas não quer dizer que funcionará como espera sempre, depende de combinar com o usuário dele não fazer nada diferente do esperado, o que não é ideal.

Comment: Então que tipo de projeto/linguagem você faria isso?

Comment: Talvez em C# mesmo, como nunca precisei, nunca estudei a fundo.